# Using multiple rstudio add-ins at the same time

Tags: rstudio, add-in

I have a scenario where i want to build a add-in which will be used to browse the amazon S3 files and user can interact with the this browser (this viewer pane will be always present). After selecting file using this browser, user can select another add-in to view charts based on content of the file selected (this chart will also be displayed in viewer pane).

Is this possible? Is there a better approach to do this?

I'm able to open only one add-in in viewer pane now at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a similar question in rstudio community and got reply that the feature of opening multiple add-ins at the same time is not available. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/221470968-Opening-multiple-add-in-at-the-same-time